# What is the difference between grubx64 and shimx64?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, refit

I'm new to Linux. I loaded Ubuntu on my Mac and I'm booting it with rEFInd. I see two choices:

1. `EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`
2. `EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`

They both boot into Ubuntu.

What's the difference between the two and which one should I use? Did I do something wrong that made both show up?

Comment: hello, shimx64.efi is the secure boot option

Comment: @mojo706 I recommend posting a (maybe only slightly) expanded version of that as an answer.

Comment: On Fedora Core there is also a third file `shimx64-fedora.efi` :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Typically, `EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` on the EFI System Partition (ESP) is the GRUB binary, and `EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` is the binary for shim. The latter is a relatively simple program that provides a way to boot on a computer with Secure Boot active. On such a computer, an unsigned version of GRUB won't launch, and signing GRUB with Microsoft's keys is impossible, so shim bridges the gap and adds its own security tools that parallel those of Secure Boot. In practice, shim registers itself with the firmware and then launches a program called `grubx64.efi` in the directory from which it was launched, so on a computer without Secure Boot (such as a Mac), launching `shimx64.efi` is just like launching `grubx64.efi`. On a computer with Secure Boot active, launching `shimx64.efi` should result in GRUB starting up, whereas launching `grubx64.efi` directly probably won't work.

Note that there's some ambiguity possible. In particular, if you want to use a boot manager or boot loader *other than* GRUB in a Secure Boot environment with shim, you must call that program `grubx64.efi`, even though it's not GRUB. Thus, if you were to install rEFInd on a Secure Boot-enabled computer, `grubx64.efi` could be the rEFInd binary. This binary would probably not reside in `EFI/ubuntu`, though; both it and a shim binary would probably go in `EFI/refind`. Also, as you've got a Mac (which doesn't support Secure Boot), there's no need to install rEFInd in this way; it makes much more sense to install rEFInd as `EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi` (its default location and name).

Note that the rEFInd documentation includes [a whole page on Secure Boot.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html) Chances are you won't benefit from reading it, user190735, since you're using a Mac. I mention it only in case some other reader comes along who's trying to use rEFInd in conjunction with Secure Boot.

Comment: Nice application , add this link too https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/SecureBoot

Comment: Did MS sign shimx64.efi then?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft signed `shimx64.efi` -- at least, the version that Ubuntu installs on Secure Boot computers. (There are also unsigned Shim binaries available; or you can [install your own Secure Boot keys and sign `shimx64.efi` yourself](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/controlling-sb.html) to take full control of your computer's Secure Boot process.

Comment: Fedora and Ubuntu have [different approaches](https://wiki.freebsd.org/SecureBoot) _after_ secure boot is succeeded (during the runtime). In former, the shim also passes on flag to the kernel to indicate that it was loaded with secure boot, and during the runtime, kernel validates all device drivers. In latter, this runtime validation by kernel is not performed.

Comment: @vulcanraven, that used to be true, but Ubuntu's been verifying kernel modules for some time now. (I don't recall when this change was made, but it's a time measured in years.) I've had to sign the modules used by VirtualBox (which installs out-of-tree kernel modules) on Ubuntu to get VirtualBox to work for quite a while now. (My script for doing so is timestamped May of 2017.)

Comment: so that I can find this later: if you dont have shimx64, and you want it, doing `sudo apt-get install shim-signed` will magically result in it appearing in the EFI/ubuntu folder, and show up in `sudo efibootmgr -v` :)

Comment: @RodSmith Maybe that's the reason why installing media codecs on Ubuntu requires adding a MOK to shim: because media codecs probably use kernel modules that Ubuntu validates.