# Install Ubuntu 16.04 on Acer Aspire E15 with UEFI

Tags: system-installation, uefi, acer

How can I install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Acer Aspire E15 E5-574-592S with UEFI?

Answer (score 1):

I have an Acer Aspire E5 and had the same problem. Follow these steps:

They assume that you are installing Ubuntu, but might also be required for booting from a Live USB

1. Make sure your UEFI is up to date.
2. In UEFI, you must set a supervisor password. Once the supervisor password is set, some new menus are accessible.
3. Enter the **Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing** menu. It will allow you to declare the newly installed Ubuntu boot image as trusted on your laptop.
4. Select **EMMC >> EFI >> Ubuntu** and select the file `shimx64.efi`. You will be prompted to give it a name of your choice (which will appear in the F12 boot options).
5. Type the name press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then **Yes** should be highlighted.
6. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again. Restart the computer without any boot disk and tap <kbd>F12</kbd> during the boot process.
7. You should now get the boot option menu with the name you chose.
8. You can change the boot order in UEFI now so that it boots directly to the GRUB screen.
9. Either disable the supervisor password, or save it in a secure place.

Comment: This answer got me underway installing Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) from a live usb onto an Acer AO1-431-C2GN "Cloudbook" 14" laptop with 2GB ram, 32GB sdd and intel celeron n3050 62bit cpu. To see the why, check out [Install Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit onto an Acer v11 touch](http://askubuntu.com/a/576605/653727) and [What is the difference between grubx64 and shimx64?](http://askubuntu.com/a/342382/653727)