# Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda6/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file!

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

My computer doesn't boot. I format my Toshiba laptop with a bootable USB drive. I make this [my_partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuuvL.png), and when i restart the computer after the installation, my computer does not boot. Then i run boot-repair and finishes with this [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOVzm.png). I reboot ant nothing happens. I review some questions before, but could't find anything yet. Can someone help me please?

Comment: You don't appear to be asking a question.

Comment: After the installation, Ubuntu won't boot, just the bootable usb drive. 
I run boot-repair and this is what i got http://paste.ubuntu.com/25923375/

Comment: @psusi can you help me?

Comment: @psusi - the question is, how do you "make your BIOS boot on sda6/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file!"? That's not the type of thing that's shown up in any BIOS I've seen.

Comment: The answer to my above question is probably to run something like `efibootmgr --create --disk /dev/sda --part 1 --loader /EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi --label "rEFInd Boot Manager" --verbose` (seen at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#efibootmgr)

Answer (score 1):

There is a blog post discussing this at http://adityagilra.blogspot.com/2014/11/fixing-ubuntu-boot-problems-with-boot.html

> """You can now reboot your computer. Please do not forget to make your
>   BIOS boot on sda1/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file!""" I think they just
>   mean that: enable UEFI and set the boot order to first boot HDD in the
>   BIOS.
>
> But you can check using efibootmgr:
>
> I installed efibootmgr using synaptic. (see
>   http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2023086)
>
> (If you're not root, use `sudo efibootmgr -v` can become root by `sudo
>   su -`) root@ubuntu:~# efibootmgr -v BootOrder: 0000,0000,0000,0000
>   Boot0000* ubuntu
>   HD(1,22,2faf1,d6f60eae-849f-43e3-836c-2280067f3161)File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)

According to [What is the difference between grubx64 and shimx64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342365/what-is-the-difference-between-grubx64-and-shimx64) `shimx64.efi` is for Secure Boot.

As noted at the Arch Boot Process:

> A boot entry could simply be a disk. In this case the firmware looks
>   for an EFI system partition on that disk and tries to find a EFI
>   application in the fallback boot path \EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI
>   (BOOTIA32.EFI on IA32 (32-bit) EFI systems). This is how UEFI bootable
>   removable media work.

Honestly, the warning message should probably be removed from that `boot-repair` utility, altho I'm not so sure it's well-maintained.