# Boot repair issues in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have a problem with my Laptop (ThinkPad E540) and I can't boot correctly. I searched errors might be useful for my case but still can't figure what should I do.
My guess is that problem comes from boot mode and I followed [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974522/please-do-not-forget-to-make-your-bios-boot-on-sda6-efi-ubuntu-shimx64-efi-file) but at the end it didn't help.
after boot repair there's this message:

```
     Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 20.04.2 
LTS entry (sdb4/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file) !
```

but I don't know how to do that.

Also please tell me how to fix my problem.
P.S [This](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hkG2zNFdGD/) is my boot repair summary

Comment: Please include text as part of the question not as a screen shot

Comment: If you have Secure Boot off, the ubuntu entry you have using grubx64.efi should work. Surprised it does not also have a second ubuntu entry that is shimx64.efi. See lines 30 that says ubuntu entry is UEFI default & details of Ubuntu entry on line 51.  You can see those same details with '`sudo efibootmgr -v` This says something was not correctly updated: "Warning: NVram was not modified." Do you have a UEFI setting that locks NVRAM? Possibly similar?  Lenovo T460S unable to update firmware fwupdate disabled boot order lock
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2455027

Answer (score 0):

Try this link on adding menu item to the `EFI` bootloader.

https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/how-to-use-linux-efibootmgr-examples