# Dual Boot Ubuntu with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I have Windows 10 installed in my laptop and i'd like to install Ubuntu 18.04 too. I just create a bootable USB and install Ubuntu (with the option 'Install alongside Windows 10')? Is there anything I need to do with Secure Boot? As i see in System Information my BIOS Mode is in Legacy and secure boot is unsupported. Do I proceed with the installation or do I have to change any values from BIOS or anywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you don't have to do anything related to secure boot in your BIOS**, thanks to `shimx64.efi` and `grubx64.efi` EFI binaries, one for Secure boot enabled and another one for not.

To read more details about the topic : [What is the difference between grubx64 and shimx64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342365/what-is-the-difference-between-grubx64-and-shimx64)

Or here's the best answer of the above question.

> Typically, EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi on the EFI System Partition (ESP) is
>   the GRUB binary, and EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi is the binary for shim.
>   The latter is a relatively simple program that provides a way to boot
>   on a computer with Secure Boot active. On such a computer, an unsigned
>   version of GRUB won't launch, and signing GRUB with Microsoft's keys
>   is impossible, so shim bridges the gap and adds its own security tools
>   that parallel those of Secure Boot. In practice, shim registers itself
>   with the firmware and then launches a program called grubx64.efi in
>   the directory from which it was launched, so on a computer without
>   Secure Boot (such as a Mac), launching shimx64.efi is just like
>   launching grubx64.efi. On a computer with Secure Boot active,
>   launching shimx64.efi should result in GRUB starting up, whereas
>   launching grubx64.efi directly probably won't work.
>
> Note that there's some ambiguity possible. In particular, if you want
>   to use a boot manager or boot loader other than GRUB in a Secure Boot
>   environment with shim, you must call that program grubx64.efi, even
>   though it's not GRUB. Thus, if you were to install rEFInd on a Secure
>   Boot-enabled computer, grubx64.efi could be the rEFInd binary. This
>   binary would probably not reside in EFI/ubuntu, though; both it and a
>   shim binary would probably go in EFI/refind. Also, as you've got a Mac
>   (which doesn't support Secure Boot), there's no need to install rEFInd
>   in this way; it makes much more sense to install rEFInd as
>   EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi (its default location and name).
>
> Note that the rEFInd documentation includes a whole page on Secure
>   Boot. Chances are you won't benefit from reading it, user190735, since
>   you're using a Mac. I mention it only in case some other reader comes
>   along who's trying to use rEFInd in conjunction with Secure Boot.

Comment: Long story short, i'm good to go?

Comment: ..Absolutely! :)

Comment: Happy to help, would you mind to mark my answer as 'Solution' or vote it up?.

Comment: Did it, my upvote is not counted because i'm a new member. But i've marked it as 'Solution'.

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead, even if secure boot was enabled Ubuntu's installer will walk you through some steps to disable it.

Comment: So everything's ok with it and BIOS Mode which is in 'Legacy'?

Comment: Yes, however it is always wise to do a backup of Windows before attempting this. I had my windows partition erased a while ago while trying to dual boot with Ubuntu 12.04 because of a corrupt usb drive.