# Add Ubuntu ISO as Boot Option via `efibootmgr`

Tags: boot, dual-boot, iso

I'm wondering how I can manipulate the boot menu on a Mac to add an option for a "Ubuntu ISO". To be 100% clear as I can see the non-answers coming, I am not looking to install Ubuntu, but just boot the ISO from the HD. From what I have researched I need to use `efibootmgr` from inside a Linux Distro to manipulate the boot options.

For example this would be what I would do with Grub:

```
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom && sudo update-grub2
 menuentry "Ubuntu ISO" {
        set isofile="/home/isos/ubuntu.iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject toram
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

But I need something like:

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Efibootmgr#Creating_a_boot_entry

```
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 2 -L "Gentoo" -l '\efi\boot\bootx64.efi' -u 'root=/dev/sda3 initrd=\efi\boot\initramfs.img quiet'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how MacBook works with EFI, but EFI can only boot only [specific](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342365/what-is-the-difference-between-grubx64-and-shimx64) executable files on EFI partition without parameters. It can not boot from ISO files. Here is the way to use grub to run Ubuntu from ISO files:

1. Create a 10GB rescue partition.
2. Format it as ext4. Label and enter name "rescue".
3. Create the `grub.cfg` file in Linux

   `$HOME/grub.cfg`:

   ```
   menuentry "Rescue Ubuntu 18.04 LiveCD" 
   {
     set isoname="/ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso"
     search --label --set rescue rescue
     loopback loop ($rescue)$isoname
     linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isoname quiet splash
     initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
   }
   ```
4. Create a [standalone](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks#GRUB_standalone) `grubx64.efi` with `memdisk` and the needed modules

   Creates binary with modules and `grub.cfg` embedded:

   ```
   grub-mkstandalone --modules="minicmd normal search search_fs_file search_fs_uuid search_label ext2 echo cat ls disk part_gpt part_msdos" \
   -o grubx64.efi \
   -O x86_64-efi --compress=xz \
   "/boot/grub/grub.cfg=$HOME/grub.cfg"
   ```
5. Create an entry in the EFI boot manager and place `grubx64.efi` inside the new entry. Add all other [files EFI expects](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342365/what-is-the-difference-between-grubx64-and-shimx64) (`BOOTX64.CSV`, `shimx64.efi`, `mmx64.efi`).

Comment: Can you post how to create the entry in EFI boot mgr? Also, there's no need for a separate partition, but I could see that being a safe route.

Comment: Basically you add a new entry and change the order of booting using efibootmgr command: 

`efibootmgr -c -L NAME -d /dev/sda -p 1 -l /EFI/entry/shimx64.efi`. Check current entries using `efibootmgr -v` first to see how parameters look.

Comment: That should be an update to the answer you gave, my downvote is locked until you edit the question. I felt the questions most important answer I wanted was the `efibootmgr` line of code so I voted accordingly, but would like to change to upvote. Will accept answer after testing. Can you confirm would this load the OS in the RAM which is my desire? I don't want any HD mounted and the ability to do partitioning on HD.