# why there are so many boot loaders after installing refind on dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

After installing ubuntu 20.04 alongside with win 10 and rEFInd, I find only leave 2 icons on the refind menu (win + ubuntu). My initial uninstallation of Grub failed with a dependency error.
Below is the output of efibootmgr:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0006,0005,0003,0002,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001  UEFI:CD/DVD Drive
Boot0002* UEFI:Removable Device
Boot0003* ubuntu
Boot0004  UEFI:Network Device
Boot0005* rEFInd Boot Manager (direct)
Boot0006* rEFInd Boot Manager
```

My questions are:

1. what's the difference between rEFInd Boot Manager (direct) and rEFInd Boot Manager? And why both are active and I only see 1 showed up? Which one should I disable?
2. 0003 ubuntu is Grub, right?
3. As there is no grub icon in the refind, how do I find efi file to include in the param dont_scan_files of refind.conf?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: To answer `2.`; yes **ubuntu** is **grub**. Sorry can't answer the other questions.

Comment: To really see details use `sudo efibootmgr -v` That will show exactly what file & folder in the ESP is used to boot. Some entries are just default UEFI entries that your vendor adds for support or a default boot of a device.

Answer (score 0):

#1 By command `sudo efibootmgr -v` I find out rEFInd Boot Manager (direct) is grubx64.efi while rEFInd Boot Manager is shimx64.efi.
The difference is explained in [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342365/what-is-the-difference-between-grubx64-and-shimx64).

#2 yes

#3 I delete the grub package via terminal