# Failed to open EFI\UBUNTU\ - Invalid parameter

Tags: boot, uefi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tpmn.jpg)

Native user ubuntu/single boot

Comment: Improve your question - see https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask. There are more questions than answers at the moment. For example - what preceded this state? Did it work before and suddenly stopped working, or did you change something?

Comment: In addition to ethcz's comment run this report (not fix, yet): Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   &           
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to open \EFI\UBUNTU\‌\*garbled\* - Invalid parameter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1355358/failed-to-open-efi-ubuntu-garbled-invalid-parameter)